# MS SQL. Установить категорию всем дочкам (и внучкам), равную категории родителя

Tags: sql, sql-server

Дана таблица:

```
|ID|Name             |IsGroup|ParentID   |Tag       |
|1 |Канц товары      |1      |NULL       |канцелярия|
|2 |Ручка            |1      |1          |NULL      |
|3 |Шариковая ручка  |0      |2          |NULL      |
|4 |Гелиевая ручка   |0      |2          |NULL      |
|5 |Карандаш         |1      |1          |NULL      |
|6 |Жирный карандаш  |0      |5          |NULL      |
|7 |Стройматериал    |1      |NULL       |стройка   |
|8 |Молоток          |0      |7          |NULL      |
```

То есть данные иерархические:

```
Канцтовары
    Ручка
       Шариковая ручка
       Гелиевая ручка
    Карандаш
       Жирный карандаш
Строматериал
    Молоток
```

У родительского элемента указана категория (Tag). 
Необходимо одним запросом пройтись и установить ту же категорию всем дочерним элементам, включая дочерние группы и элементы дочерних групп. Чтобы получилось так:

```
|ID|Name             |IsGroup|ParentID   |Tag       |
|1 |Канц товары      |1      |NULL       |канцелярия|
|2 |Ручка            |1      |1          |канцелярия|
|3 |Шариковая ручка  |0      |2          |канцелярия|
|4 |Гелиевая ручка   |0      |2          |канцелярия|
|5 |Карандаш         |1      |1          |канцелярия|
|6 |Жирный карандаш  |0      |5          |канцелярия|
|7 |Стройматериал    |1      |NULL       |стройка   |
|8 |Молоток          |0      |7          |стройка   |
```

MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа так:

```
WITH cte(ID,Tag)
AS
(
    SELECT ID,Tag
    FROM datatable
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ID,cte.Tag
    FROM datatable t, cte 
    WHERE cte.ID = t.ParentID
)
UPDATE datatable
SET datatable.Tag = cte.Tag
FROM cte
WHERE datatable.ID = cte.ID
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить словами, что творится внутри скобок "AS"?

Comment: [WITH common_table_expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175972%28v%3dsql.105%29). Особенно "Guidelines for Defining and Using Recursive Common Table Expressions".